# I'm trying to do an EOF but is not working in the second time that enter in the loop

Tags: c++

I don't know what is it wrong with my program. Please Help me.
There is my code, he is very simple, but my problem is on the EOF.
I got no compilation error, after insert the value of string, the While is executed and i put the b variable value. After this, he break the while, but i need to digite more values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string a;
double resultado;
int ct=0,b,soma=0;
while(getline(cin,a))
{
    cin>>b;
    ct++;
    soma+=b;
}
resultado = soma / ct;
std::cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(1)<<resultado<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

Actual Output:

Input:
Julio Cesar
410
Carlos Roberto -- Here he break the while and not execute with another name.
200

Output: 
205

Expected Output:
305 -- (410+200)/2 -- value 2 is the counter.

Comment: *What* EOF do you mean? Do you get compilation errors? Please edit your question to include them (complete and unedited) in that case. Is there something else that gives you problem? Please try to describe it better.

Comment: Also note that `soma / ct` is an *integer* division, so you won't ever get fractions from that.

Comment: For some specific input, what is your actual *and* expected output?

Comment: I can get fractions values, if i divide 482 by 3. It is 160.7

Comment: i will edit my actual and expected output

Comment: The input: Julio Cesar 410 Carlos Roberto 200
Is in the same line, right?